# SMTP email configuration on Ghost: Error with magic link?

Tags: configuration, config, digital-ocean, blogs, ghost-blog

I installed ghost on a droplet on Digital Ocean. I install it directly from the marketplace. I bought a custom domain from Namecheap and also an email. I got the domain working. But when I setup my email. The email is being sent from noreply@atharv.vadehra’.‘me according to error logs. I want it to be sent from noreply@vadehra.me an alias which I created.

This is the config file:

```
"mail": {
    "from" : "noreply@vadehra.me",
    "transport": "SMTP",
    "options": {
      "host": "mail'.'privateemail.com",
      "port": 465,
      "secure": true,
      "from": "atharv@vadehra.me",
      "auth": {
        "user": "atharv@vadehra.me",
        "pass": "**************"
      }
    }
  },
```

Error Log:

```
{"name":"Log","hostname":"ghostonubuntu2204-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-
01","pid":211762,"level":50,"version":"5.47.1","err":{"id":"440e9970-fadc-11ed-9f77-
ad3b785d7a29","domain":"https://atharv.vadehra.me","code":"EENVELOPE","name":"EmailError","st
atusCode":500,"level":"normal","message":"Failed to send email. Reason: Can't send mail - all 
recipients were rejected: 553 5.7.1 <noreply@atharv.vadehra.me>: Sender address rejected: not 
owned by user atharv@vadehra.me.","help":"\"Please see https://ghost.org/docs/config/#mail for 
instructions on configuring email.\"","stack":"Error: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 553 
5.7.1 <noreply@atharv.vadehra.me>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user 
atharv@vadehra.me\n    at createMailError 
(/var/www/ghost/versions/5.47.1/core/server/services/mail/GhostMailer.js:68:12)\n    at 
SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/www/ghost/versions/5.47.1/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-
connection/index.js:790:19)\n    at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT 
(/var/www/ghost/versions/5.47.1/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1632:28)\n  
  at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> 
(/var/www/ghost/versions/5.47.1/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1585:30)\n 
   at SMTPConnection._processResponse 
(/var/www/ghost/versions/5.47.1/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:953:20)\n  
  at SMTPConnection._onData (/var/www/ghost/versions/5.47.1/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp
-connection/index.js:755:14)\n    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData 
(/var/www/ghost/versions/5.47.1/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:193:44)\n 
   at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)\n    at addChunk 
(node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)\n    at readableAddChunk 
(node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)\n    at TLSSocket.Readable.push 
(node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)\n    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead 
(node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)","hideStack":false},"msg":"Failed to send email. 
Reason: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 553 5.7.1 <noreply@atharv.vadehra.me>: 
Sender address rejected: not owned by user atharv@vadehra.me.","time":"2023-05-
25T09:12:25.995Z","v":0}
```

I tried moving the from attribute up and down but still does not work. Also according to the code for the email in GhostMailer.js

```
function getFromAddress(requestedFromAddress) {
**    const configAddress = config.get('mail') && config.get('mail').from; **

    const address = requestedFromAddress || configAddress;
    // If we don't have a from address at all
    if (!address) {
        // Default to noreply@[blog.url]
        return getFromAddress(`noreply@${getDomain()}`);
    }

    // If we do have a from address, and it's just an email
    if (validator.isEmail(address, {require_tld: false})) {
        const defaultSiteTitle = settingsCache.get('title') ? settingsCache.get('title').replace(/"/g, '\\"') : tpl(messages.title, {domain: getDomain()});
        return `"${defaultSiteTitle}" <${address}>`;
    }

    return address;
}
```

The from argument should be read nothing is working. It shows the same error in error log. Also, every time I make a change I make sure that I restart ghost.